# Is password cracking noisy?

Tags: password-cracking, facebook

I was wondering if servers can pick up password cracking? If they can, how would I protect myself from being detected?

My friends have let me practise on their accounts, but I don't know if Facebook will pull me up and blacklist my IP or something.

Comment: You do know that not all password cracking is the same right? Hashed passwords from a database are cracked offline. But bruteforcing web services, like you suggest, will definitely be picked up because you're sending thousands of requests.

Comment: I obviously don't, or I wouldn't be asking the question...

Comment: If you're trying to crack someone else's Facebook password, you probably shouldn't even if the account owner gives you the permission to attempt that. The reason being that it's Facebook's system that you're cracking, so the account owner doesn't actually have the authority to give you permission to crack his account (unless by "friend", you mean Mark Zuckerberg).

Comment: Note that even if your friends let you do that, you may be still violating the TOS of Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Online*** password cracking, where you try different passwords against the actual service (e.g. Facebook) is incredibly noisy, since you are basically flooding the target with requests. On any serious system you are bound to be detected and blocked rather quickly.

You could try to spread out your attempts over longer times, direct them at different accounts and use different IPs. But unless it is a very simple password you don't have time to spare, and you will probably be detected anyway.

***Offline*** password cracking is done in the privacy of your own home, and is therefore only noisy in the sense that it will cause your fans to spin a lot. But to crack a password offline you need to have the hash, and Facebook aint giving you that.

Finally do note that practising password cracking on your friends Facebook account is probably ***illegal*** and definetely a violation of their terms of service, even if you have your friends permission. You risk getting into serious trouble here. There are plenty of vulnerable-by-design systems out there that meant to be used to practice hacking on. I'd recommend you play around with one of those instead. In the long run, it will be more fun.

Answer (score 2):

Define "noisy".

If I pull a NTLM hash from a Windows System, and attempt to brute force it, only I, myself, am aware of the brute force attempts.

Using the same scenario, but attempt to brute force on the same system, it would be fairly obvious due to increased resource usage.

Attempting to break into a web account is going to draw attention. Because for each password, you make a request to the server. Many websites now feature time-outs, locational restrictions, and others to prevent/deter brute-forcing a password.